# Spring water in basement of new construction

Tags: water, basement, construction

Location: Northern New Brunswick, Canada
Lakeside property.

Last fall we dug and poured our concrete foundation, which has a full height basement and a walk-in, which needed a step foundation in that area.  While digging the step foundation, we hit rock bed at approximately 5ft bellow the normal footing elevation.

During the dig, we didn’t hit any water source.  The dig and concrete pour went as planned.  However since winter came early, we didn’t pour the concrete floor right away.  So we went through the winter with a compacted gravel floor in the basement, just waiting for warm weather.

When spring came along, I had water come in the basement, and I was happy to have installed a drain tile along side the inside of the footing with a sump and pump.

But now that all the snow and spring melt is over, I still have water coming in the basement at one specific place in the gravel floor. It’s at a slower rate, but it seems to be a spring source, since it even created a small hole in the gravel floor where the water comes in.

Now I was thinking of running a drain line from that ‘hole’ direct to the sump, but i’m wondering if I should go even further to permanently fix this problem before pouring the concrete floor...  Does anyone have any good ideas?

Comment: You should consider yourself lucky that the problem showed up before the concrete floor of the basement was poured.  This gives you the opportunity to correct the problem, in ways others have described, without having to jackhammer through concrete.  Many homeowners aren't that lucky.

Answer (score 1):

I have had several daylight basements, the thing to do now is to install drains from beyond the spring to outside the building envelope, if you do this no pump will be needed. If it was my place I would install a drain on the 3 sides with drains at each end of the home, as far as other problems this will eliminate any problems the weeping of the spring in natural and the water will run no matter what you do so provide an easy path for it to get outside the building and you won’t have to plug the pump in.

Comment: I agree, but what I am afraid of is that new drain line that goes under the footing outside the building envelope could become a new incoming source of water if ever the lake level comes up too high in the spring. This year the level was only about 6 inches below my basement grade.  This being said, I think this is still the best option, I will install a check valve on the line just before going under the footing, thus having access from inside..

Comment: If the lake level rises this much it really won’t matter with a daylight basement, I have a similar issue with my property the drains go to a creek, when the water level comes up the drains are slow but they do still drain, if the water level raises above the floor level water will find a way in, so it is better to drain the real issue you have now or don’t and fight a wet basement for the life of the home on the chance the lake water rises two far these are your options. I would put in drains in now.

Comment: Agree with Ed that if the lake rises, nothing short of a watertight door will keep the water out of your basement.  Do what you can now to take care of the problem that you now have.

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem ,put a rubber gasket was added to make like a pool to keep water out and foundation was sealed for that. Stone and drain pipes added . water table very high. And a sealed sump pump added to keep floor dry.Adding a sump may run all the time. Just had to.  Good luck. We keep the water pused out can not pump the water table .Wish i went slab instead.

Comment: I already have a sump, but am somewhat afraid of having it run almost all the time.  Since my floor isn’t poured yet, I was even thinking of adding an additional drain line from the source, go under the slab outside to atmosphere, but this could create another problem if the lake water level goes extra high...

Comment: Yes, we lost the fight and took every thing out of basement.Raised sump .cause kept running to much floor  damp sometimes. Should have come up another foot and would have been out of water table.

Comment: It ran from May to August.Bills out of this world.

Comment: The last straw was when lake came up and water came into basement windows. Big mess.Had a nice indoor pool.